# why can't convert Symbian CRSAPublicKey to descriptor?

Tags: symbian

code as following:

```
const CRSAPublicKey& iRSAPublicKey = mRSAKeyPair->PublicKey();
const TInteger& e = iRSAPublicKey.E();
HBufC8* exponent8 = e.BufferLC(); //failed to get the right result,it's garbled
TInt ei = e.ConvertToLongL();    //converted successfully,ei=65537
```

can anyone tell me why BufferLC() doesn't work?is something important i just have missed?,and how to convert a TInterger to descriptor?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It't not garbled, it just the integer's binary representation [as stated in the documentation](http://developer.symbian.org/main/documentation/reference/s3/pdk/GUID-E3D3C429-EA8C-34C1-9D1D-9062BC3D4F16.html#GUID-14F7DA24-8AD8-39E4-B21E-69307AB0A557). The same way as the byte `0x33` is the binary representation for ASCII `3`.

I assume you want something printable of the `TInteger`. For small `TInteger`s for which `IsConvertableToLong()` is true, you can use the `ConvertToLong()` approach with one of the `TDes::AppendNum()` overloads. For larger integers, I think you need to roll your own conversion function. The most straightforward way is probably just to output the binary representation bytes as hex.

---

Edited to add: Here's an untested snippet for doing the hex conversion.

```
HBufC8 *bin = theTInteger.BufferLC();

// One binary byte yields two hex bytes
HBufC8 *output = HBufC8::NewL(bin->Length()*2);
TPtr8 outP = output->Des();

// Loop through the binary bytes  
for (int i = 0; i < bin->Length(); ++i) {
  TUint8 const KHex[] = "01234567890abcdef";
  TUint8 binByte = (*bin)[i];

  // Output high nibble (4 bits)
  outP.Append(KHex[(binByte & 0xf0) >> 4]);

  // Output low nibble
  outP.Append(KHex[binByte & 0x0f]);
}

CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy(bin);
```

Comment: thanks laalto.but how to ouput the binary representation bytes as hex?

Comment: TInterger member data:protected: //Member data
 enum TSign {EPositive=0, ENegative=1};
 TUint iSize;
 TUint iPtr;

Comment: i try to  for (TInt i = 0; i < bit / sizeof(TInt); i++)
 {
  //bit shit,so 
 }

Comment: how to use TInteger member function:TInteger& operator <<= (TUint aBits);?

Comment: thanks a lot,but there is an exception inside the for loop { Exception at function:inline TUint8 &TDes8::operator[](TInt anIndex)}.

Comment: another problem,how to output the binary representation bytes as demical number instead of hex?

Comment: @user356048: Yeah, as the code was not tested, there was a bug: `HBufC::NewL()` takes in a max length parameter but the descriptor length itself is 0. Indexing beyond that panics with USER 22. I changed them to `Append()` calls.